# Excel taking more time open >10k records :apache poi

Tags: excel, apache, apache-poi

I have read the data from Jtable and write date to excel using apache poi.

My Code:
Initialise the sheet:
 public XlsxVisitorFactory(String title) throws IOException {

```
    tempFile = File.createTempFile("Test", ".xlsx");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();        
    out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
   rowIndex = 0;
    sh = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");
    if (title != null) {
        Row row = sh.createRow(++rowIndex);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(title);
    }
    createHeaderCellStyle();
    createHyperLinkCellStyle();
    createWrapTextCellStyle(); 
}
```

.....
once data is added in the cell.

In the footer i have written the below code to open the file.

```
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
            Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempFile);
```

Please help.

public class XlsxVisitorFactory implements TableVisitorFactory {

```
private File tempFile;
private FileOutputStream out;
private Workbook wb;
private Sheet sh;
private Row currentRow;
private int rowIndex;
private static Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(XlsxVisitorFactory.class);
private  CellStyle headerStyle;
private Font headerFont;
private XSSFCellStyle hyperlinkStyle;
private CellStyle wrapStyle;

public XlsxVisitorFactory() {

}

// Create a tempFile to use
public XlsxVisitorFactory(String title) throws IOException {
    tempFile = File.createTempFile("Test", ".xlsx");
    tempFile.deleteOnExit();
    wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    out = new FileOutputStream(tempFile);
    rowIndex = 0;
    sh = wb.createSheet("Sheet 1");
    if (title != null) {
        Row row = sh.createRow(++rowIndex);
        Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue(title);
    }

}

private class TableGroupVisitor implements TableVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(String tableName, int columnCount) {
        if (tableName != null) {
            Row row = sh.createRow(++rowIndex);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(tableName);
        }
    }
}

private class DocumentFooterVisitor implements NameVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(String name) {
        try {
            Row row = sh.createRow(++rowIndex);
            Cell cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(name);
            wb.write(out);
            out.close();
            //Desktop.getDesktop().open(tempFile);
            //InputStream is = new FileInputStream(tempFile);
            //StreamingReader.builder().rowCacheSize(100).bufferSize(4096).open(tempFile.g//etAbsoluteFile());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Unable to start Excel: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}



private class TableCellVisitor implements CellVisitor {
    @Override
    public void visit(String name, int index) {
        if (index == 0) {
            currentRow = sh.createRow(++rowIndex);
        }

        Cell cell = currentRow.createCell(index);
            String nameNoHtml = name.toString().replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "");
            cell.setCellStyle(wrapStyle);
            if (isDouble(name)) {
                cell.setCellValue(Double.parseDouble(nameNoHtml));
            } else {
                cell.setCellValue(nameNoHtml);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void visitForColumnWidth(final int actualRowCount) {

        for (int x = 0; x < actualRowCount; x++) {
            sh.autoSizeColumn(x);
          }

}

@Override
public void visitForColumnWidth(int actualRowCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public XSSFSheet readFromExcel(File file) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream ins = new FileInputStream(file);
    // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(ins);

    // Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    ins.close();
    return sheet;
}

public void setRowIndex(int rowIndex) {
    this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
}
public TableVisitor createTablePageBreakVistor() {
    // TODO add logic for page break
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isPageBreakAllowed() {
    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: There is not really a question in your question. It seems to be about "taking more time open >10k records". But more time than what else? And of course takes writing more records more time than writing less records. That's law of nature. And your code looks useless to me. The `XlsxVisitorFactory(String title)` looks like a constructor. But then? How the main data gets added? And what is meant by "footer" in terms of code? Please refine your question.

Comment: sorry for complete info.I have added complete code. hope this may help you

Comment: From Jbutton action,     I am calling this print method.                public void printToExcel(String title) {
        try {
            .print(table_obj, new XlsxVisitorFactory(title), "at " + DateUtil.dateToStringIncludingMinutes(DateUtil.now()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Could not export to Excel", e);
        }
    }